# Can't access string in a method body

Tags: c#, string, boolean

The code that I have

```
private bool isValidNumber(string myString)
{
    const int VALID_LENGHT = 10;
    bool valid = true;
    if (myString.Lenght == VALID_LENGHT)
    {
        foreach (char ch in myString)
        {
            if (!char.IsDigit(ch))
            {
                valid = false;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        valid = false;
    }
    return valid;
}
```

And the error that I have when I tried to check myString.Lenght

> Error  1   'string' does not contain a definition for 'Lenght' and no extension method 'Lenght' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: It is [`Length`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) not `Lenght`.

Answer (score 3):

It's spelled "Length" not "Lenght".

Comment: I really doubt this question _deserves_ an answer..

Comment: @Soner The OP followed the rules and also provided the code HE worked on so yes this question does deserve an answer even if the answer seem trivial/obvious.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem :** Error is straight forward there is no `Lenght` property for in string class.

**Solution :** you just need to replace `Lenght` with `Length`

Replace This:

```
if (myString.Lenght == VALID_LENGHT)
```

With This:

```
if (myString.Length == VALID_LENGHT)
```